# How can I deselect one button when I select another?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web-frontend

I have an online menu where I'd like to select either noodles or rice, but not both.
When I select a button some CSS happens.

I tried using jquery to do this and it still allows me to select both and doesn't deselect the other.

Am I missing something glaringly obvious?

```js
function selected(clicked) {
  var ans=3 - clicked;
  var noodles=$("1");
  var rice=$("2");
  var noodlesID=1;
  var riceID=2;
  switch (ans) {
    case 1: document.getElementById(riceID).classList.toggle("select");
    if (noodles.hasClass("select")) {
      document.getElementById(noodlesID).classList.toggle("select");
    }
    break;
    case 2: document.getElementById(noodlesID).classList.toggle("select");
    if (rice.hasClass("select")) {
      document.getElementById(riceID).classList.toggle("select");
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

```css
/* added by editor for demo purpose */
.selected {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="productimg" id="1" onclick="selected(this.id)">
<img src="images/plainnoodles.jpg" alt="">
<div class="productName">
Noodles
</div>
</button>

<button class="productimg" id="2" onclick="selected(this.id)">
<img src="images/plainrice.jpg" alt="">
<div class="productName">
Rice
</div>
</button>
```

Comment: as a general piece of advice, don't mix jquery and javascript. Either write everything in JS or everything in jquery.

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a few issues in your logic which need to be addressed:

- Don't mix native JS methods and jQuery. Stick to one or the other, otherwise you end up with some confused code which is more difficult to maintain.
- The id selectors in your JS code need to be prefixed with `#`
- The class selectors in your CSS code need to be prefixed with `.`
- The class name you apply in the JS is `select` yet in the CSS you define it as `selected`
- Don't use inline event handlers in your HTML, ie. `onclick`. This is bad practice. Use delegated event handlers, bound in JS code. You can then use the `this` keyword within the event handlers to reference the element which raised the event.
- Use DOM traversal methods to relate content to each other to make the logic generic. Don't use things like `switch` or multiple `if` conditions to change logic flow for multiple cases - otherwise you will have to update the JS every time the HTML changes, which is exactly what you need to avoid.
- You need to `remove()` the class from the buttons which were not clicked, not `toggle()` it.

With all that said, here's a working example which caters for an infinite number of buttons:

```js
let productButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.productimg');

productButtons.forEach(productButton => {
  productButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let button = e.currentTarget;
    productButtons.forEach(btn => btn !== button && btn.classList.remove('selected'));
    button.classList.toggle('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.selected { border: 2px dashed red; }
```

```html
<button class="productimg" id="1">
  <img src="images/plainnoodles.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="productName">Noodles</div>
</button>

<button class="productimg" id="2">
  <img src="images/plainrice.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="productName">Rice</div>
</button>

<button class="productimg" id="3">
  <img src="images/pizza.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="productName">Pizza</div>
</button>
```

Note that the above is using plain JS. If you wanted to use jQuery instead, the code would look like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $productButtons = $('button.productimg').on('click', e => {
    let $button = $(e.currentTarget);
    $productButtons.not($button).removeClass('selected');
    $button.toggleClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the proper HTML element for this: two radio buttons.

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="dish" value="noodles" /> Noodles</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="dish" value="rice" /> Rice</label>
```